# How to block an attacker with "no-data" IP address and how can this be possible?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, cpanel

I have an attacker with "no-data" IP address accessing my website, I looked at the cpanel Latest Visitors Stats and I do not know how can this be possible?

Comment: How do you know he's an attacker?

Comment: He's trying to access non-existing privileged admin pages

Comment: I am also seeing this attached to the URL that I didn't get before: ?rand=1365984000000

Comment: I'm guessing you're getting hit by some script someone wrote that just checks many sites for the same vulnerability. Looks like it's trying to use a whole bunch of random numbers hoping you used some kind of url id that will let him get some user's session. It'll try a whole bunch of things, and log if it gets something out of your site so the person running the script can come back later and see what he found. If it doesn't find anything, it'll stop soon and as long as it didn't find a hole, you'll be fine.

Comment: In the logs, I check that with my own IP address requests accessing the site I get that, but I am not writing that variable on the URL and this never happened before, so even my requests get this how?

Comment: For an HTTP connection, TCP is needed, so a valid IP address. However, if your application thinks to be 'fancy' and logs headers like `X-Forwarded-For` etc. instead of the IP address... it could very well be empty. Never trust those headers (or only trust them from proxies under your control).

Comment: Thanks I checked the original logs and there it is the full IP address with a HEAD request

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there's an attacker and you block his ip address, he'll just use a proxy. You can't really win like that. Just make sure you don't have any obvious security holes, and eventually he'll give up and go away. Depending on how sensitive the information he's trying to get at is, make sure to watch for it being accessed, or for changes in your site, but other than that just let the little guy tire himself out.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, you're right I know, I still would like to know how could he have a "no-data" on the IP address?

Comment: As to that I don't know. I've never seen that before. Hopefully someone else comes along and can tell you that. Or you can keep googling. I'll give you an upvote for some visibility.